# How to find a unimodular integer matrix $T$ satisfying $T^\top A T=B$ given symmetric integer matrices $A,B$?

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear, searching

Given two unimodular **symmetric integer matrices** $A$ and $B$,
I asked how to find a **unimodular integer** $T$ that satisfies this nonlinear relation between $T$ and $A,B$ like this in Mathematica:

```
Transpose[T].A.T == B
```

This means that we have the following conditions:
$$A_{ij}=A_{ji}, B_{ij}=B_{ji},$$ and
$$\det A, \det B, \det T \in \{+1,-1\}.$$

[I asked on Mathematica StackExchange here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/293896/95437), but the unsolved question was wrongly closed as a duplicate. Specifically [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/251537/95437) does **not** solve the problem given the above constraints.

You can tell the answer cited there does not work -- it does not produce an integer $T$ matrix. In general, Mathematica output for the claimed answer in the previous post like `B.MatrixPower[Inverse[B].Inverse[A], 1/2]` and $(B^{-1}A^{-1})^{1/2}$ gives a non-integer matrix, failing to satisfy the above conditions. In fact the quoted answer does not even solve a rank-2 toy model correctly.

Let me provide a different $A$ and the same $B$:

```
A = {{2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
     {-1, 2, -1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0},
     {0, -1, 2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
     {0, 0, -1, 2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
     {0, 0, 0, -1, 2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
     {0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0},
     {0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, -1, 0, 0},
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 2, 0, 0},
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1}};
     
B = {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
     {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
     {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
     {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1}};
```

### Hint

There indeed exists an integer $T$ matrix solve the equation `Transpose[T].A.T == B`:

```
T = {{-5, -5, -5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 8, 16},
     {-10, -10, -10, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 15, 30},
     {-8, -8, -8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 12, 24},
     {-6, -6, -6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 9, 18},
     {-4, -4, -4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 6, 12},
     {-2, -2, -2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 6},
     {-7, -7, -6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 10, 20},
     {-4, -3, -3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 10},
     {1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -3, -4},
     {-2, -2, -2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 7}};
```

My question now is: Could you provide an algorithm to search for the integer matrix $T$ efficiently for a large-rank matrix? (in this case, it is a rank-10 matrix)

I believe [`ResourceFunction["GramianReduce"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/GramianReduce/) may help.

Comment: It's a good question.

Comment: In an earlier version of this question you gave two smaller examples. Try `A={{0,1},{1,0}};B={{0,1},{1,2}};T={{t1,t2},{t3,t4}};FindInstance[Transpose[T].A.T==B&&(Det[T]==1||Det[T] ==-1),Flatten[T],Integers,5]` and `A={{0,1},{1,0}};B={{2,5},{5,12}};T={{t1,t2},{t3,t4}};FindInstance[Transpose[T].A.T==B&&(Det[T]==1||Det[T]==-1),Flatten[T], Integers,5]` both of which quickly give you multiple integer unimodular matricies T which satisfy your equations. Time those. Then time 5x5 and 6x6 and ... and see if you can estimate the amount of time it will take to find solutions for 10x10. Then you are done

Comment: @Bill There could (in principle) be a slick algorithmically reasonable way to do this that we're just failing to see. That would be of interest.

Comment: Thanks, Bill. I know the smaller rank-2, one of the two examples (I gave) can still be solved by T= B.MatrixPower[Inverse[B].Inverse[A], 1/2], the other cannot.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I ALWAYS assume there is someone much much brighter than I who can see a slick algorithmic solutions that I will never find. My tiny offering here was only to present to him that there was at least one way in Mathematica to get a few small solutions.

Comment: @zeta `FindInstance` doesn't seem to be able to find more than the two solutions and the negatives of those solutions for each of your rank 2. It might be interesting to see if that is the case for every possible rank 2 example. And it might be interesting to see every possible rank 3 and rank 4 example and all their solutions. Maybe from that you might be able to guess something. I am only guessing, but perhaps the positive and negative solutions might be because of your +1 and -1 determinant for T. You might try to find a way to prove that.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I can't fully back this up, but I'm of the opinion that there _isn't_ a slick (read efficient) way to do this beyond just using a sat-solver / NLIP. Because an efficient solution to this would appear to greatly simplify the lattice isomorphism problem which is known to be difficult in higher dimensions.

Comment: @flinty Maybe you are correct. I had thought the isomorphism problem involved an inverse (rather than transpose) on one side but I'm probably mistaken on that.

Comment: Show us how the matrices `A` and `B` were created...

Comment: @azerbajdzan OP may be doing it differently, but you could create example problems like this:

```{m1, m2} = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {2, 10, 10}];
T = First@HermiteDecomposition@m1;
A = First@HermiteDecomposition@m2;
B = Transpose[T] . A . T;```

Would be good to know also why zeta needs to solve this apparently difficult problem: What physical problem does finding T actually solve, or is this just a mathematical curiosity?

Comment: @flinty: Your matrices are not symmetric.

Comment: @azerbajdzan oh right. Easy to fix though: - just turn A into a gram matrix: `A = Transpose[A].A;`

Comment: @flinty: If I am not mistaken this way you produce only positive definite matrices but OP matrices are both non-positive definite.

Comment: @azerbajdzan this brute force method appears to work: https://pastebin.com/iHh4Ne6U The resulting A,B are symmetric, unimodular, and not positive definite, though it has a preference for determinants of A,B being -1 for some reason. Again, would help if OP explained how to generate such problems.

Comment: Thanks all - the matrices have something to do with sphere packing and modular form in math. :)

Comment: Are you trying to find lattice isometries?

Comment: I don't think these are direct lattice nor they shall have lattice isometries.

Comment: @flinty thanks what do you mean by
  A = Transpose[A].A ???

Comment: Indeed, your matrices are not positive definite. For positive definite, T can be found with `IsIsometric` in magma.

Comment: @zeta `A = Transpose[A].A` does $A\leftarrow A^\top A$ , i.e computes $A^\top A$ from the old A, then assigns this result to `A` from this point onwards. It ensures that A is symmetric, and if det A is +/- 1 then it also ensures the $A^\top A$ determinant is 1. However it does force the new A to be a gram matrix i.e positive.

Please elaborate on this: _something to do with sphere packing and modular form in math. :)_

Comment: You can also represent your equation as $(T^\top\otimes T^\top)\mathrm{vec}(A)-\mathrm{vec}(B)=0$ , where $\otimes$ is the `KroneckerProduct` . Not sure that helps however. Here $\mathrm{vec}$ is the vectorization operator which stacks columns of a matrix, or in Mathematica `vec = Flatten@*Transpose;` This is now conceptually simpler, although a 100x100 dimensional linear problem of find the matrix $\mathbf{M}$ in $\mathbf{Ma}=\mathbf{b}$ but you then need to do a _"Kronecker square root"_ on $\mathbf{M}$ to get $T^\top$.

Comment: Hi @zeta. Do you have references for any algorithm for these transformations? Or can you give some indication of application so I might check where this decomposition arises?

Comment: @zeta if you happen to know more than one pair of $\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{B}$ related by the same $\mathbf{T}$, you can potentially further constrain the entries of $\mathbf{T}$. I asked about this [as if it was a matrix cipher here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/109560/what-weaknesses-are-worth-investigating-in-this-non-linear-matrix-cipher/109561#109561) to see if any cryptanalysis methods could be brought in to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

If you implement your example by
$$\text{Table}[A_{ik} == \sum_{st}T_{si}\ B_{st}\ T_{tk},\{i,1,n\},\{k,1,n\}]$$
you get $n^2$ quadratic constant forms for n^2 variables, that, by elimination, produce algebraic expressions with powers higher than 4.

So even exact complex valued solutions are not at hand,  if the system does not factor into a complete chain of solvable subgroups. Numerical complex solutions are fast.

The minors of T given, range up to 300. There will be no other way as brute force search over a lattice of 300^8.

On the other hand, a search for working examples is not faster, the determinant condition is only a reduction of complexity by 1 equation of order x^n.